# Scala as a shell script: jars on the classpath

Tags: scala, jar

You can run a scala script as a linux shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#

println("Hello")
```

In one such script I need to load classes from a group of jars (which happen to be in the same directory as the script). If this were the REPL I could use `:jar`, but that's not available in script mode.

I'm trying to set the `-classpath` parameter:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -classpath '.:./*.jar' "$0" "$@"
!#

import javax.media.jai.{JAI, RenderedOp}
```

but the compiler just can't find the classes:

```
error: object media is not a member of package javax
import javax.media.jai.{JAI, RenderedOp}
             ^
```

How do I include these jars?

Comment: Using `'` will prevent glob expansion, so it will look for a file _named_ `*.jar`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason, the glob (`*.jar`) wasn't working. I was able to get the script running by putting in all the libraries by hand:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -cp lib/jai_codec.jar:lib/jai_core.jar:lib/mlibwrapper_jai.jar $0 $@
!#

import javax.media.jai.{JAI, RenderedOp}
```

I don't know *why* the glob isn't working though.

Note that in this case I don't have the `.` in the classpath because the script itself is provided as an argument. In many cases though you will need to include it:

```
exec scala -cp .:lib/jai_codec.jar:lib/jai_core.jar:lib/mlibwrapper_jai.jar $0 $@
```

---

Based on [this helpful post](http://mackaz.de/26), I have a script header that pulls in every jar in a `lib` folder, even if the script (or the folder it's in) are symlinks.

```
#!/bin/sh
L=`readlink -f $0`
L=`dirname $L`/lib
cp=`echo $L/*.jar|sed 's/ /:/g'`
/usr/bin/env scala -classpath $cp $0 $@
exit
!#
```

- The first line turns the given script location `$0` into its actual location on disk, expanding symlinks.
- The second line removes the script name and adds `/lib`
- The third line creates a `cp` variable with all the jars separated by `:`
- The fourth line runs scala, wherever it may be.
- The fifth line exits. This probably isn't necessary, but it makes me feel better.

Comment: Shell globs work only when they match file names. This won't work in a path since ':' is a valid filename character. Also, when globs do match, they'll output a _space-separated_ list of filenames.

Comment: Add the -savecompiled compiled option to make the script execute faster after the 1st time.

Answer (score 10):

```
exec scala -classpath ./*.jar $0 $@
```

will work

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. The import statement fails with an error message such as: `error: object jai is not a member of package com.sun.media`  The class in question is definitely in one of the jars, I checked.

Comment: Hm. I don't know. It just works for me. I have checked with some jar

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you use SBT instead to handle it. See the [scripts wiki](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Scripts), which explains how to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas
!#

/***
scalaVersion := "2.9.0-1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-twitter" % "0.8.3",
  "net.databinder" %% "dispatch-http" % "0.8.3"
)
*/

import dispatch.{ json, Http, Request }
import dispatch.twitter.Search
import json.{ Js, JsObject }

def process(param: JsObject) = {
  val Search.text(txt)        = param
  val Search.from_user(usr)   = param
  val Search.created_at(time) = param

  "(" + time + ")" + usr + ": " + txt
}

Http.x((Search("#scala") lang "en") ~> (_ map process foreach println))
```

Comment: This works but it makes it makes running the simplest script take about 8 seconds, every time, any way around that to make it faster even in subsequent runs?

Comment: @MohamedRagab I think it can save up on some of the work done, but I'm not sure. A hot JVM is probably more important, such as you can get with [Nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/).

Comment: @DanielCSobral sure Nailgun would help, to my understanding the overhead of starting the JVM is below half a second, and SBT caching saves a bit more time of course. It would be great if some of the processing done here is avoided if not needed, I am playing with an attempt to check first in the bash script the existence of the JAR files in the ivy cache and then adding them to the classpath directly

Comment: @MohamedRagab Did you make any progress? Is there a way to start SCALA repl backed with .jars inside ivy2 cache?

Comment: A few years later, **[Ammonite](http://www.lihaoyi.com/Ammonite/#ScalaScripts)** offers a comprehensive solution for writing Scala scripts

Answer (score 2):

To avoid to define classpath definition in every header you can define a function that wraps your scala executable in (for example) your .bashrc and make it visibile to outer scope:

```
...
function scala() {

    PARAMS=( "$@" )

    FILENAME=${PARAMS[0]}
    REMAINING_PARAMS=(${PARAMS[@]:1:${#PARAMS[@]}})

    CUSTOM_CLASSPATH_DEF=".:/whatever/*"
    /path/to/scala -cp "$CUSTOM_CLASSPATH_DEF" -Dscala.color=true "$FILENAME" "${REMAINING_PARAMS[@]}"
}

export -f scala 
...
```

Now you can define your header as:

```
#!/bin/bash
scala "$0" "$@"
exit 0
!#
```

(You can still use REPL typing 'scala' from command line)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.scalaclass.com/node/10
This should work for you. I just fix the dependency according to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also put single quotes around the classpath with a glob, like this:

`exec scala -classpath '.:*.jar' "$0" "$@"`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on Cygwin

```
#!/bin/sh

me=`basename "$0"`

exec scala "$me" "$@"

!#

  ...
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about `jars on the classpath`

Comment: This actually helped me to find those jars. Otherwise if I just do exec scala "$0" "$@", I will get an error message like "No such file or class on classpath".